Save chart as png from dash
This is my code:
def plot_data(df, metallo, port = 1276):
    # Initialize the Dash app
    app = Dash(__name__)

    # Define the layout of the app
    app.layout = html.Div([

        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
        html.P("Starting point of the interval:"),
        dcc.Slider(id="start-slider", min=1, max=len(df['Commercial Undertakings_net'])-1, value=(len(df['Commercial Undertakings_net'])-52), step=1),
        html.P("Maximum lag:"),
        dcc.Slider(id="lag-slider", min=1, max=len(df['Commercial Undertakings_net']), value=(len(df['Commercial Undertakings_net'])), step=1),
    ])

    @app.callback(
        Output("graph", "figure"),
        [Input("start-slider", "value"),
         Input("lag-slider", "value")]
    )
    def update_bar_chart(start, lag):
        # Slice the data based on the selected interval
        comm_data = df['Commercial Undertakings_net'][start-1:start+lag-1]
        print(comm_data)
        noncomm_data = df['InvestmentFunds_net'][start-1:start+lag-1]

        index_values = df['Data'][start-1:start+lag-1]

        # Create bar traces for comm_net and noncomm_net
        # comm_trace = go.Bar(x=index_values, y=comm_data, name='Commercials')
        noncomm_trace = go.Bar(x=index_values, y=noncomm_data, name='Investment Funds',marker=dict(color='red'))

        # Create layout with secondary y-axis, legend, and centered, bold title
        layout = go.Layout(
            title=f"<b>Commitment of Traders LME - {metallo}</b>",
            titlefont=dict(size=16, color='black', family='Arial',),
            yaxis=dict(title='Comm & Inv.Fund Net'),
            showlegend=True,
            title_x=0.5 
        )

        # Create a figure with both traces and layout
        fig = go.Figure(data=[noncomm_trace], layout=layout)


        return fig


    app.run_server(port=port)

which returns me this:

Rather than everytime click on the dashboard to download the image as png, isn't possible to write a line of code that does it automatically?
I tried with:
        # Save the figure as PNG
        fig.write_image(f"COTR{metallo}.png")

but is not working because is not displaying me anymore the plot. ANy suggestions?
